# Signing a request with a hmacSHA25 signature in Postman using a pre-request script for NiceHash API

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to sign a request to access the `NiceHash API`.

Please see the requirements for signing the request here:
https://www.nicehash.com/docs/

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("hmac", CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(pm.request.headers, 'mySecret'));
```

Here is what my `X-Auth` Header looks like:
X-Auth: my-key:{{hmac}}

I have a feeling I am not satisfying the input param to the `HmacSHA256` function. They are saying:

> Input is a byte array composed of ordered fields using zero byte
> (0x00) as a separator. There is no separator before the first field or
> after the last field. Some fields are always empty in which case the
> separators immediately follow one another. If converting HTTP header
> values, and url parts from string to byte representation you should
> use ISO-8859-1 encoding. For request body you should use the raw bytes
> as they are sent to the server. For JSON messages the character
> encoding should always be UTF-8.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I keep getting a `401` unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss their specs. What you cited is followed by the list of ordered fields you are supposed to include, in their order

- API Key
- X-Time request header value
- X-Nonce request header value
- Empty field
- X-Organization-Id request header value
- Empty field
- Request method
- Request path
- Request query string
- Request body

This list is supposed to be followed, field by field and used to compute the signature, using this 0x00 as a separator between fields, in specific encoding and a rule to skip empty fields.

Instead, you just seem to use `pm.request.headers` as a HMAC argument. Not sure what exact structure of this object is but I highly doubt it contains all fields mentioned above, in correct order and with correct separators between fields.